# What are the performance implications of unified (vs non unified) memory?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, performance

When seeing the term "***unified*** memory" in the new MacBook Pro copy<sup>1</sup>, I cannot determine what impact it will have on day to day use of the device, save for an educated guess that it will make reading and writing from RAM faster, and therefore improve the speed of most operations - but this is only a guess - and I have no idea how to estimate *how much* faster operations will be.

What are the impacts of *unified* memory (vs a similar device with non-unified memory), and quantitatively how important is the difference?

<sup>[1](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro/16-inch)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54977/how-much-gpu-memory-do-iphones-and-ipads-have/54978#54978

Comment: https://eclecticlight.co/2021/10/23/explainer-unified-memory/